# If checkbox box clicked other checkbox in a row should hide in tableview using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
    - (IBAction) creatorAction:(id)sender
{
    button=(UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger tag = [button tag];
    NSLog(@" creator :%ld",(long)tag);
    button.selected = !button.selected;
    if(button.selected)
    {
        button.selected = TRUE;
        NSLog(@" creator status :%d",button.selected);
        NSObject *creatorData = [totalString objectAtIndex:tag];
        NSLog(@"creator data added: %@",creatorData);
        Creator[tag]=@"True";
        if((Creator[tag]=@"True"))
        {
            Modifier[tag]=@"True";
            [modifierButton setHidden:YES];
            Approver[tag]=@"True";
            [approverButton setHidden:YES];
        }
    [cs addObject:creatorData];
    }

    else
    {
        button.selected = FALSE;
        Creator[tag]=@"False";
        if((Creator[tag]=@"False"))
        {
            Modifier[tag]=@"False";
            [modifierButton setHidden:NO];
            Approver[tag]=@"False";
            [approverButton setHidden:NO];
        }

        NSLog(@" creator status :%d",button.selected);
        NSObject *creatorData = [totalString objectAtIndex:tag];
        NSLog(@"approver  data removed: %@",creatorData);
        // [createrArray removeObject:creatorArray];
        [cs removeObject:creatorData];
    }
       NSLog(@"Final creater array: %@",Creator);
       NSLog(@"Final cs array: %@",cs);
     //modifierButton.enabled = NO;
}

- (IBAction) modifierAction:(id)sender
{
    button1=(UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger tag = [button1 tag];
    NSLog(@" modifier :%ld",(long)tag);
  //NSLog(@"%d",AddAdminViewController.selectedId));
    button1.selected = !button1.selected;
    if(button1.selected)
    {
        button1.selected = TRUE;
        NSLog(@" modifier status :%d",button1.selected);
        NSObject *modifierData = [totalString objectAtIndex:tag];
        NSLog(@"modifier data added: %@",modifierData);
        Modifier[tag]=@"True";
     // [modifierArray addObject:modifierArray];
        [ms addObject:modifierData];
    }
    else
    {
        button1.selected = FALSE;
        Modifier[tag]=@"False";
        NSLog(@" modifier status :%d",button1.selected);
        NSObject *modifierData = [totalString objectAtIndex:tag];
        NSLog(@"approver  data removed: %@",modifierData);
     // [modifierArray removeObject:modifierArray];
        [ms removeObject:modifierData];
    }
    NSLog(@"Final Modifier array: %@",Modifier);
    NSLog(@"Final ms array: %@",ms);
}

- (IBAction) approverAction:(id)sender
{
    button2=(UIButton *)sender;
    NSInteger tag = [button2 tag];
    NSLog(@" approver :%ld",(long)tag);

  //NSLog(@"%d",AddAdminViewController.selectedId));
    button2.selected = !button2.selected;
    if(button2.selected)
    {
        button2.selected = TRUE;
        NSLog(@" approver status :%d",button2.selected);
        NSObject *approverData = [totalString objectAtIndex:tag];
        NSLog(@"approver data added: %@",approverData);
        Approver[tag]=@"True";
        [as addObject:approverData];
    }
    else
    {
        button2.selected = FALSE;
        Approver[tag]=@"False";
        NSLog(@" approver status :%d",button2.selected);
        NSObject *approverData = [totalString objectAtIndex:tag];
        NSLog(@"approver  data removed: %@",approverData);
     // [approverArray removeObject:approverData];
        [as removeObject:approverData];
    }
    NSLog(@"Final Approver array: %@",Approver);
    NSLog(@"Final as array: %@",as);
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  NSLog(@"Hello %lu",(unsigned long)[totalString count]);
  return [totalString count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";
 // NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-1.png"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

    creatorButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    [creatorButton addTarget:self action:@selector(creatorAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [creatorButton setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [creatorButton setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    creatorButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    creatorButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    creatorButton.selected = NO;
    [cell addSubview:creatorButton];
    button.selected = FALSE;
    NSLog(@"creator tag:%ld",(long)creatorButton.tag);
    NSLog(@"Index row value %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    modifierButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    [modifierButton addTarget:self action:@selector(modifierAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [modifierButton setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [modifierButton setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    modifierButton.tag =indexPath.row;
    modifierButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    modifierButton.selected = NO;
    [cell addSubview:modifierButton];
    button1.selected = FALSE;
    NSLog(@" Modifier tag :%ld",(long)modifierButton.tag);

    approverButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(375.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    [approverButton addTarget:self action:@selector(approverAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [approverButton setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [approverButton setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    approverButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    approverButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    approverButton.selected = NO;
    [cell addSubview:approverButton];
    button2.selected = FALSE;
    NSLog(@" Approver tag :%ld",(long)approverButton.tag);

    UIImage *profileImages = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
    cell.imageView.image = profileImages;
    cell.textLabel.text = [totalString objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Above is the code where if one checkbox clicked other checkbox in same row should hide in tableview with multiple same rows. When i clicked 1st checkbox from row its hiding last object checkboxes. I have added three buttons in one row which replicates same depending on rows. How it should done?[image: Attached image here]

Comment: what issue faced here ?

Comment: If i click creator checkbox of perticular row then remaining modifier and approver should hide but in my case it hiding last row modifier and approver rather than first row.

Comment: I can help you.But you have to be patient.

Comment: Yes you can, i have patience to listen

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
      1. set this tag in your cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
creatorButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    [creatorButton addTarget:self action:@selector(creatorAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [creatorButton setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [creatorButton setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    modifierButton.tag =100;
    creatorButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    creatorButton.selected = NO;
    [cell addSubview:creatorButton];
    button.selected = FALSE;
    NSLog(@"creator tag:%ld",(long)creatorButton.tag);
    NSLog(@"Index row value %ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    modifierButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    [modifierButton addTarget:self action:@selector(modifierAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [modifierButton setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [modifierButton setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    approverButton.tag = 101;
    modifierButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    modifierButton.selected = NO;
    [cell addSubview:modifierButton];
    button1.selected = FALSE;
    NSLog(@" Modifier tag :%ld",(long)modifierButton.tag);

    approverButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(375.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
    [approverButton addTarget:self action:@selector(approverAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [approverButton setImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [approverButton setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    modifierButton.tag =102;
    approverButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    approverButton.selected = NO;
    [cell addSubview:approverButton];
    button2.selected = FALSE;
    NSLog(@" Approver tag :%ld",(long)approverButton.tag);





   - (IBAction) creatorAction:(UIButton *)sender{
            UITableViewCell *cell =(UITableViewCell*)sender.superview.superview; // track cell as your view hierarchy 
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblViewNews indexPathForCell:cell];
            UIButton *creatorButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
                UIButton *modifierButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
                UIButton *approverButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
                sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
                if (sender == creatorButton  ) {
                    modifierButton.hidden = sender.isSelected ? YES : NO;
                    approverButton.hidden = sender.isSelected ? YES : NO;
                }
                else if (sender == modifierButton  ) {
                    creatorButton.hidden = sender.isSelected ? YES : NO;
                    approverButton.hidden = sender.isSelected ? YES : NO;
                }
                else if (sender == approverButton  ) {
                    creatorButton.hidden = sender.isSelected ? YES : NO;
                    modifierButton.hidden = sender.isSelected ? YES : NO;
                }

                }
```

Comment: Yes i had done but hiding only one checkbox from 4th row

Comment: did you set tag as per my suggestion . and removed exist tag also ?

Comment: and use same selector method for button .

Comment: Yes i set same tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath and called that button. can you do update same in my original code if you don't mind. I am bit confused about it

Comment: Okay i will check and let you know

Comment: Its working good but hiding 4th row modifier and approver. Its not applying to all row that i have in table.

Comment: you need to hide all modifier and approver while creatorButton selected ?

Comment: My issue is if i selected creator button then from that row of modifier and approver should hide not all modifier and approver

Comment: then this solution according to your expalnation .

Comment: NO, Its working fine for 4th row but same not happening to all rows that i have in table as mentioned in image too.